# integrate phpList in custom page

Tags: php, email, phplist

I created account on phpList.com. Currently using hosted phpList. It is sending email to user when s/he signs up. But i want to integrate phpList in my custom page.

Ex. I have this website 
[exchangedeluxe.com](http://www.exchangedeluxe.com), in which i want to send email using phpList when user signs up.

I searched but couldn't find a tutorial or any help to do so.

**Question**

How i can integrate with phpList in my custom page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all run phplist.sql query into your website database. then upload lists folder(which is inside public_html folder) to your site root directory. after that change config.php file inside lists/config folder. change hostname($database_host) mysql database name($database_name), mysql username($database_user) and password($database_password).
now you can login to phplist at http://www.exchangedeluxe.com/lists/admin/

Comment: do i need to copy whole lists folder or only contents of lists folder?

Comment: If i have created index.php locally and installed phpList in local system. How can i manage both of these. If user clicks on sign up in index.php files which i have created it should insert email in list which i have created using phpList and send email to that email address.